# Auto complete feature for DatePicker in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, autocomplete, datepicker

I am building a silverlight 4 application and the user wants to have a autocompelte feature for 
date controls. ( Note I am using the DatePicker). For e.g. when the user types 5 and tabs out 
the date should be converted to 5'th of sept 2012 becuase 5'th august has gone past. I also have 
some other rules that are in place for this date formation. I planned to write some code 
for this one in the KeyUp event but I am unable to get the text that the user has entered in the 
datepicker. Also TextInputStart and TextInputUpdate are never called in my case.

I am looking for the correct event in which I can get what the user has entered

Thanks
Amol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem once with the `DatePicker` of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). The only way I could solve that was to create a new `UserControl` using a standard `TextBox` and a `DatePicker`. I re-styled the `DatePicker` so that its default text area remained hidden, and replaced it by the standard `TextBox`.
I wired the `DatePicker`'s `SelectedDate`-Property to the `Text`-Property of the `TextBox`, so that it would get updated once someone picks a date.

In your case you could use the `AutoCompleteBox` coming with the Toolkit instead of a standard `TextBox` and then use some clever logic to prefill the list of auto-complete proposals. Thus your control would look like a standard `DatePicker`, and mostly behave like one, but would provide a mixed functionality of `DatePicker`, `TextBox` and `AutoCompleteBox`.

Comment: Wow! This answer is about five years old! I hope it helped you somehow! :)